# Has anyone worked with the SharePoint Guidance Repository Pattern?

Tags: 2007, patterns-and-practices

Any issues faced when using libraries and lookup columns?

Please share you thoughts and experiences as I am planning to use it.

Comment: this question have many answers, so it should be marked as community wiki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have done quite a bit of work with the Microsoft SharePoint Guidance Repository code. We ran into issues using lists/libraries that contain lookup columns. This is because the code that fills the mapped properties of an entity from an SPListItem tries to get the value of the field using item[fieldmapping.ListFieldId] which of course doesn't work in the case of a lookup column.

We modified this code to check if the field was a lookup column first and if so pull the value out correctly using the SPFieldLookupValue class.

Hope this helps

Alex

Comment: Agree!! It's still evolving, Even I had to tweak the code to fit my needs , like avoid mapping the ID while updating, lookup columns..etc